# Make a line of source code bold in MediaWiki

Tags: c++, mediawiki

I'm using a default install of MediaWiki and am trying to emphasize a certain line of code to students in a lab text I am writing.

Specifically, I am trying to bold the template line in:

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
```

This doesn't work:

```
<code>
<b>template <typename T></b><br>
class Node {
</code>
```

Is there a way to do this in default MediaWiki?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the brackets by entity references, `&lt;` etc.?

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't appear to work, unfortunately.

Comment: In response to the "close" vote: I questioned posting this on SO also, since this is really more of a markup language than a programming language. However, I couldn't think of a more appropriate StackExchange site than SO. Recommendations are welcome, though.

Comment: Well, some people feel that if a topic isn't really covered here then you should try whatever the go-to forum is for that (like the MediaWiki mailing list).  But I'm empathetic to the idea that a lot of those places are clunkier and not moderated, so being close-happy in edge cases like this prevents testing of the waters for questions that might be someday migrated to another StackExchange-style site.

Comment: I agree. After experiencing StackExchange, I'll really never be comfortable posting questions whose answers really matter to me in another type of site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precise thing you've written seems to work on mediawiki.org, I just tried it in the sandbox:

http://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Sandbox&oldid=429106

It's a very subtle bolding effect.  But it's definitely different than when you don't have the `<b>` tags.  You might need to throw in some CSS for bolded things to make it more obvious:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CSS

A note on a question you didn't ask (but I answered initially anyway): if you're not inside a code block, the nonsensical markup language of MediaWiki uses **`'''three apostrophes'''`** to bound bold text and *`''two for italics''`*:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting

I'd imagine if your installation is a default, all the things in that document will work.  Wikipedia has some extensions installed so you can't necessarily get the things there that you see when you click "edit" on a page to work.  That would be fun stuff like the chess boards, for instance:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EmbedChessboard

Another unsolicited note I'll throw in is that I like to use bold to distinguish declarations and references.  So I write things like:

template <typename **T**>
    class **Node** {

I also like my code to use proportional fonts and tabs.  :)

Comment: Thanks for testing it and for the CSS info.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, and I was trying to put that on a wiki that doesn't have the `<source lang= ???>` tag set up, I would type it up in my favorite text editor (Notepad ++ 6.x), take a screen-shot, paste the screenshot into paint, crop it out the way I want it to look, save it to a XXsource.png picture file, upload it to the wiki, and include it on the page where I want it.